# How to check if a station exists out of facts of stations and lines in PROLOG

Tags: prolog, predicate

I have written the following facts to represent a tube map

```
station(AL,[Metropolitan]).
station(BG,[Central]).
station(BR,[Victoria]).
station(BS,[Metropolitan]).
station(CL,[Central]).
station(EC,[Bakerloo]).
station(EM,[Bakerloo,Northern]).
station(EU,[Northern]).
station(FP,[Victoria]).
station(FR,[Metropolitan]).
station(KE,[Northern]).
station(KX,[Metropolitan,Victoria]).
station(LG,[Central]).
station(LS,[Central,Metropolitan]).
station(NH,[Central]).
station(OC,[Bakerloo,Central,Victoria]).
station(PA,[Bakerloo]).
station(TC,[Central,Northern]).
station(VI,[Victoria]).
station(WA,[Bakerloo]).
station(WS,[Northern,Victoria]).
```

I need to write a predicate of form

```
station_exists(Station)
```

to check if a station exists, but I can't figure out how to write the rule. I've tried something like:

```
station_exists(Station):- station(Station,_)
```

But it returns true for any station name. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your constants start with an uppercase, so Prolog considers these to be *variables* not constants.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constants start with an uppercase, so Prolog considers these to be *variables* not constants.

You should rewrite these to start with an uppercase, or a quoted atom:

```
station(al, [metropolitan]).
station(bg, [central]).
station(br, [victoria]).
station(bs, [metropolitan]).
station(cl, [central]).
station(ec, [bakerloo]).
station(em, [bakerloo,northern]).
station(eu, [northern]).
station(fp, [victoria]).
station(fr, [metropolitan]).
station(ke, [northern]).
station(kx, [metropolitan,victoria]).
station(lg, [central]).
station(ls, [central,metropolitan]).
station(nh, [central]).
station(oc, [bakerloo,central,victoria]).
station(pa, [bakerloo]).
station(tc, [central,northern]).
station(vi, [victoria]).
station(wa, [bakerloo]).
station(ws, [northern,victoria]).
```